# Is it possible to invoke signalr from ActionResut which returns a default view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

I have a POST method in mvc which saves a customer and it redirects to Index View by default.

Now I want to include a notification if the customer is created. I have tried the basic SignalR implementation but I am not sure how I can invoke SignalR from an ActionMethod so that it will be reflected in client.

My confusion is redirecting to Index and invoking the client using SignalR can be written in the same Acton method, or is it required to use other method from the client after the customer is saved.

Here is the code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveCustomer(Customer customer)
{
    //Save Customer
    db.Customer.Add(customer);
    db.SaveChanges();

    // Notify Client something similar this 
    //$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    //chat.server.send(customer.Name);
    //});

    ChatHub chat = new ChatHub();
    chat.Clients.Send(customer.Name)
    RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

In my Layout page I have messagenotificationPartialView

```
$(function () {
    // Reference the auto-generated proxy for the hub.  
    var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
    // Create a function that the hub can call back to display messages.
    chat.client.send = function (customerName) {
    //add to a span
};
```

I am not sure if I am in the right direction. Is this the right way or are there any other options to implement this?

Comment: That depends.  Does your redirect to action redirect to a full view load?  In addition, is this post being invoked by ajax or a normal page post?  If you are already in the process of redirecting, your hub will break and will need to re-initialize, making it impossible to communicate with the client at that point.

Comment: In that case, this isn't going to work.  You'd need to establish a connection after the redirect, then push to the client.

Comment: is it like, once the save part is completed and redirected. we need to call $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
   chat.server.send(customer.Name);
   }); from cshtml page

Comment: Yes, though you'll run into a race condition most likely because your redirected action will try to invoke a hub that is not yet started

Comment: any other way to notify with normal post in mvc, way to invoke from controller post action

Comment: You'd have to embed something in your view that knew of the redirect, created the hub, fired a startup event to the server that the server could use to respond back with.  All in all, I think you're using the wrong approach for a persisted signalr connection

Comment: But my scenario is when the customer is saved. I want to notify it in layout view. Can you suggest the correct way of doing it.

Comment: I tried it  with this  var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatterBox>();
        context.Clients.All.say("HELLO FROM ABOUT"); but websocket  connection id was showing some error

Comment: Can you suggest the rignt way

Comment: I'd recommend doing a partial view response load so that you are not redirecting and leaving the page.  That way your hub will remain open.